# jquery tabs access from urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i have jquery tabs and want to access them from url using # but know know how can I full fill with it

requirement is mywebsite.com/#show_page1 will show the page 1 content 
and if access from mywebsite.com/#show_page2 will show the page 2 content

here is the my js code

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_tabbed a").click(function(){ 
        var id =  $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.split('_');
         $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
        $("#menu_container #show_"+id[1]).fadeIn();
                    // remove classes from all
        $("a").removeAttr("style");
        // add class to the one we clicked
        $(this).css("background-color","#1aaede");
        // stop the page from jumping to the top
        return false;

    });
    $("#menu_container #show_page1").show();
    });
});
```

and html i have is

```
<div id="nav_tabbed">
                    <a id="show_page1" style="background-color:#1aaede;">Page 1</a> <a id="show_page2">Page 2</a>
               </div>

               <div id="menu_container">
                    <div id="show_page1">
                     <!-- content here -->
                    </div>

                    <div id="show_page2">
                      <!-- content here -->
                    </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.hash;` will give you the hash value added in the addressbar and you can use it the way you need to. My suggestion is added below.

What seems to me you want to hightlight your link with the hash located in the browser's addressbar and respective div you want to show. If this is what you want to implement then you can try this with slight changes in the markup and js:

#### CSS:

```
.active {
    color:red;
}
#menu_container div {
    display:none;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="nav_tabbed"> 
    <a href="#show_page1" class='active'>Page 1</a> <!--This lets you add hash in the addressbar--> 
    <a href="#show_page2">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div id="menu_container">
    <div id="show_page1" style='display:block;'>Page 1</div>
    <div id="show_page2">Page 2</div>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
$(function () {
    // below works for hash added in the browser.
    var hash = location.hash;
    if(hash.length){
        $('#nav_tabbed a').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu_container div').hide();
        $('#nav_tabbed a[href*="' + hash + '"]').addClass('active');
        $('#menu_container div[id*="' + hash.slice(1) + '"]').show();
    }
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
    // below works for click of the anchors
    $('#nav_tabbed a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu_container div').hide();
        $('#menu_container div[id*="'+this.getAttribute('href').slice(1)+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

#### [A sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqh0qqjw/2/)

Comment: thanks it works but a problem here, on initially it removes the div how can i set any default div???

Comment: You can add `active` class to respective anchor and add the `display:block` corresponding div.

Comment: great but little problem here if access page from browser e.g. mypage.html#show_page2 it won't loads the actual required div

Comment: Wouldn't it be more simple to just trigger a click on the tab and let the jQuery tabs handle all the hiding, displaying and highlightling stuff?

Comment: @wawa yeah that would be great but OP doesn't seem to be working on jQuery ui tabs.

Comment: @Jai true, but in his post on line 3 there's a listener to the click event. So if you trigger a click on that element it will catch it. `jQuery('a#show_page2').trigger('click');` for example should work. NOTE: the id `show_page1` and `show_page2` are used on multiple elements (an `<a>` tag and a `<div>` tag. This is wrong. An id can only be assigned to one element in the dom. Most modern browsers can handle this error and just ignor it, but still there's no guarantee.

Comment: @wawa are you sure in my code you are able to see `show_page1, show_page2` ids on multiple elems.

Comment: @Jai nope your code is fine (: was talking about the code of the OP there (should have pointed that out)

Comment: yeah right but OP is getting it worked though and left.

Comment: it works not bro but i want to prevent users to scroll down the page becuase this one is used in the middle but when you open new with the # it moves down to the activated div so how can we keep users on the top

Comment: `$(document).scrollTop(0);` add this after `if` condition block.

Answer (score 0):

your posts shows a little confusion on the topic.
so first for explanation: 
there are two meanings of a #
in a url, the # is a reference to the location hash.
in jquery, the # is a reference to an element id.

you want to use the hash change in this case.

first of all... why do you wrap the window.load around the dom.ready event? 
as far, as i understood, jquery's dom ready fires when the dom is ready, jquerys window.load fires, after all images, iframes, plugins etc. have been loaded. so a dom.ready inside a window.load is kind of unnecessary ...

next: ID's have to be unique - you can't give your anchor the same id as the assigned div!

so let's get down to business - the html:

```
<div id="nav_tabbed"> 
    <a href="#page1" class="activeLink">Page 1</a>  
    <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="page1" class="contentTab activeTab">123</div>
    <div id="page2" class="contentTab">456</div>
</div>
```

we use activeLink and activeTab classes to determine which tab is currently open

the css just sets the background of the activeLink:

```
.activeLink {
   background-color:#1aaede;
}
```

the js:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".contentTab:gt(0)").hide(); //on initial load, we hide all content tabs, despite the first one

  $("#nav_tabbed a").click(function () { //the click handler for the navigation only toggles the class to change the background color
    $(".activeLink").removeClass("activeLink");
    $(this).addClass("activeLink");
  })

  if(location.hash) //here we check, if there already is a location hash set onload and then change to the desired tab
  {
    $(".activeTab").hide();
    $(location.hash).show().addClass("activeTab");
  }

});

//our hashchange event handles the loading of the desired tabs:
window.onhashchange = function () {
  if(location.hash!=null) //this checks, wether the hashchange event has been fired, due to a deletion of the hash via url
  {
    $(".activeTab").hide().removeClass("activeTab"); //hide the current tab
    $(location.hash).show().addClass("activeTab"); //show the clicked tab
  }else //and per default show the first tab
  {
    $(".activeTab").hide().removeClass("activeTab"); //hide the current tab
    $(".contentTab:first").show().addClass("activeTab"); //show the clicked tab
  }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ex46ndg1/3/