# Jquery keep users on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today i asked a question to which has been resolved but i am facing a very little browser problem that when when users open my link with the hash tag it divert them to the active div but i want to keep them on the top of the page 
so the problem is when someone vist my website from this example link

mywebsite.com/mypage.html#page1

i dont want users to scroll down to the actived div but want to keep them on the top of the page

Here is my code

CSS:

```
.active {
    color:red;
}
#menu_container div {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_tabbed"> 
    <a href="#show_page1" class='active'>Page 1</a> <!--This lets you add hash in the addressbar--> 
    <a href="#show_page2">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div id="menu_container">
    <div id="show_page1" style='display:block;'>Page 1</div>
    <div id="show_page2">Page 2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var hash = location.hash;//hash added in the browser.
    if(hash.length){
        $('#nav_tabbed a').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu_container div').hide();
        $('#nav_tabbed a[href*="' + hash + '"]').addClass('active');
        $('#menu_container div[id*="' + hash.slice(1) + '"]').show();
    }
    // below works for click of the anchors
    $('#nav_tabbed a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu_container div').hide();
        $('#menu_container div[id*="'+this.getAttribute('href').slice(1)+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

Here is the reference link of my question: [jquery tabs access from urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396228/jquery-tabs-access-from-urls/27397224)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$(function(){
    document.location.hash = ""
})
```

can work: after you have loaded your page, a internal link dont force reload..

Answer (score 0):

When you visit mywebsite.com/mypage.html#page1 and there is an element with the id of page1 in the document you can't prevent the browser to scroll down to it. The easiest solution is to remove the element with the id. The ugly solution is to scroll to the top of the page with after load of the page

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 }, 0);
```

Comment: i added this but still not working $(document).ready(function($) {
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
});

Comment: @blmstr put a 100ms timeout, fixes issues in older browsers

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that could be adding a mock `id` and then changing to the true ID on document ready:

```
$("page1-mock").attr("id","page1");
```

Or you may do as suggested in other answers, so far all seem legit too.